# IIS ImageResizer getting 504 gateway timeout error after moving to another IIS Server

Tags: iis, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

**now:** we have asp.net project that use ImageResizer to crop images and It caches on Disk. below packages installed by Nuget:

```
ImageResizer.3.4.3
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.3.4.3
```

and below my Web.config resizer section:

```xml
  <resizer>
    <diagnostics enableFor="Localhost"/>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MyProject.ImageResizerLocalReader"/>
      <add name="DiskCache"/>
        <add name="DefaultSettings"/>
    </plugins>
    <sizelimits imageWidth="3200" imageHeight="3200" totalBehavior="ignorelimits"/>
    <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true"/>
      <defaultsettings explicitSizeScaleMode="Both"/>
    <clientcache minutes="10080"/>
  </resizer>
```

it works properly without problem on production edge

**goal:** we want to transfer images and this project to another server (windows VM). configuration on both VMs are the same (IIS Version, Installed Softwares, Windows Revision, RAM and CPU Resources etc). even project works and it serve images properly when we manually test it (before moving it to production network)

**problem:** after changing VM network to production, server randomly respond with too high response time and it often responses 504 Gateway Timeout Error. but on current server all is OK! (even both VMs are the same)

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

---

My custom plugin (MyProject.ImageResizerLocalReader) code goes in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/sadeghmohebbi/53b0f367daa165756e084ff8a8ff9f23

Comment: I've had this before when there were mistakes in my network routing, DNS, load-balancer or firewall config. Try using tracert to see where the requests are going and where they might be getting blocked.

Comment: It looks like you have a custom plugin, can you share that code inna gist?

Comment: Also, 3.4.3 is a 2014 version that is very unsupported. I would suggest Imageflow.NET Server if you can upgrade, or ImageResizer 4 at minimum.

Comment: @tgolisch it works fine before production network, even sometimes respond. I don't think that these causes occurred related to network

Comment: @LilithRiver gist created and question updated. Thanks

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 504 error.

Comment: Gateway timeout isn't usually an ImageResizer thing, but might be from the redis server, which you're writing to on every single request. The difference is probably one of request volume.

Comment: Please upgrade to Imageflow, there have been security bugs since 2014.